# Create space above navigation

Tags: html, css

so i need to create some space above the nav of my site to move my navigation downwards but using margin-top just makes a white lap above the header background, i need the space to be in the background to move the nav downwards.

Here is my current code:
HTML: http://pastebin.com/8Z1xuzUC
CSS: http://pastebin.com/h3FFnQ3Y

Sorry if this sounds kind of convoluted but i can't really explain it any better.

Comment: don't even look into your code, but looks like you need `padding-top` instead of `margin-top`.

Comment: I think @KingKing is right. Have a look at the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your #header and #div in your css and add padding-top to #nav.